# Rounding result to 2 decimal places

Tags: objective-c

I have  rounded the  'legInches' but how do I round this to 2 decimal points instead of none?

specifically - (int)round(legInches)

```
result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm / %din", (int)legCentimetres, (int)round(legInches)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach:

```
result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm / %.2fin", (int)legCentimetres, legInches];
```

But this doesn't format the number properly for people that expect something other than a period for the decimal separator. For that you should use an `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *legInchesStr = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(legInches)];

result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm / %@in", (int)legCentimetres, legInchesStr];
```