# Round Float Value

Tags: objective-c, rounding

is there any way to display only the `first two numbers` of a int?

490009423985

Result 49

i need only the 49. Any way to do this? i can split the int in characters, but i think theres a better way to do this

best regards

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973442/492405

Comment: its close to what i need. I update my question :)

Comment: `int firstTwo = 490009423985 / 10000000000;`, perhaps?

Comment: yea great idea but i don't know the length of my float :) can be 49 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `log10` to figure out how many digits and then use int devision to remove digits

like [this](https://ideone.com/SWzeXk)

```
int digits = 2;
unsigned long long n = 490009423985;
for (int i = log10(n) - digits; i >= 0; --i) n /= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without a loop:

```
uint64_t value = 490009423985;
int result = floor(value / pow(10, ceil(log10(value)) - 2));
```